# Can I give an Ant Design Icon a custom URL?

Tags: reactjs, antd

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
<Button> <Icon type="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/17/17216.svg" /> </Button>
```

Is this possible, or do I need to create a local iconfont instead?

Comment: Have you tried ?

Comment: Yes. No luck. Icon stays white.

Comment: It is not possible to give URL like this. I mean, it won't work the way you want it to be.

Answer (score -2):

One solution I've found is:

```
      <Button style={{ 
       backgroundImage: 'url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/17/17216.svg")', 
       backgroundSize: '100%' }} 
      />
```

Maybe someone knows a more elegant way but this works for now.